# PHP mail() и почтовые клиенты

Tags: joomla, php

Здравствуйте! Сделал небольшой модуль для joomla 2.5, простая форма которая отправляет письмо на почту.

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: www.maxicom.ru <info@maxicom.ru>' . "\r\n";
//Отправка сообщения
mail("bogachov-webadvert@yandex.ru","Online заявка",$apply,$headers);
```

Выше по коду формируется сообщение (переменная $apply), файл находится в кодировке UTF-8 (Без BOM). На обычную почту письмо приходит нормально, а вот в почтовых клиентах например thanderbird с кодировкой беда. Подскажите что делать? Может какие-то параметры добавить в заголовки, моет ещё что-то? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОТправляйте в кодировку utf-8, не забудте отдельно кодировать в utf-8 тему письма (subject ) и имя отправителя (From)

в противном случае если пиьсмо будет ок, то тема письма и имя отправителя, если там будут присутствовать русские буквы, тоже будет кракозябрами.

А еще лучше вместо mail использовать какойто класс, напримре из PEAR есть класс Mail.

Answer (score 1):

Всё разобрался, скопировал скрипт не глядя, вот тут:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

надо кодировку UTF-8 указать и всё гуд. =)